# InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized option "email" under "fos_user.registration"

Tags: email, symfony, fosuserbundle

Following the [doc](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/emails.md), I still cannot find what is the cause behind the following error:

```
InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized option "email" under "fos_user.registration"
```

My configuration is:

```
fos_user:
  db_driver: orm
  firewall_name: main
  user_class: Members\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Entity\User
  registration:
        email: 
            template: MembersManagementBundle:Registration:confirmation.html.twig
        confirmation:
            enabled:    true
            from_email:
                address:        registration@acmedemo.com
                sender_name:    Acme Demo Registration
  service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
  resetting:
    email:
        from_email:
            address:        resetting@acmedemo.com
            sender_name:    Acme Demo Resetting
        template: MembersManagementBundle:Registration:resetting.html.twig
```

I verified indention rules and the template `MembersManagementBundle:Registration:confirmation.html.twig` physically exists. Additionnaly as you see, template of resetting doesn't create any problem. What could be the things I am missing? Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `email` does not exist in the [configuration reference](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/configuration_reference.md) for `registration` section. It only exists for `resetting` section.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I explained in answer. Thank you very much. +1

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you spend a lot of time trying to figure out what is the cause of an issue, till you post it on SO and find after solution yourself.

There is no possible parameter with name `email` under `registration`, so solution is to do:

```
 registration:
        confirmation:
            template: MembersManagementBundle:Registration:confirmation.html.twig
```

Instead of:

```
registration:
        email: 
            template: MembersManagementBundle:Registration:confirmation.html.twig
```

Which is not similar to resetting and requires no analogy.